# make image clickable and on click open corresponding text file in new window

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

when date is clicked on Image it should open new tab and load that date txt file in new tab 
for example when 28/03/2019 is clicked in new tab 28/03/2019.txt should open`image dates should be clickable and on click specific text file should get open``

Comment: can you please share code whatever you tried so far

Comment: sorry?, date(s) on one image? multiple image? how are you getting those images?

Comment: this **28/03/2019.txt** format would not work

Comment: @VISHALSINGH I want completely new code on which i will have <img src="img.jpg"></img> but when i hover on 28/03/2019 it should be clickable and new tab should open with that text file and when i hover on 27/03/2019 it should open new tab with 27/03/2019 text file

Comment: @Jah basically make dates clickable and on click open new urls

Comment: `I want completely new code `. You came to the wrong place. StackOverflow is not a free code making site. Try freelancing sites. They will be more than happy to help you for $ of course. Good luck

Comment: @itsvinit i hope you are looking for image area map. please go through this link - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question:

```html
<a href="28-03-2019.txt" target="_blank">
  <img src="image_name.jpg"/> 
</a>
```

Comment: I want completely new code on which i will have <img src="img.jpg"></img> but when i hover on 28/03/2019 it should be clickable and new tab should open with that text file and when i hover on 27/03/2019 it should open new tab with 27/03/2019 text file

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617106/how-to-have-multiple-links-from-one-image-in-rails

Comment: @itsvinit : you dont use </img> on the end of an image html tag

Comment: You probably want image area map as @VISHALSINGH mentioned in comments. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap